# Encryption Technique in WSO2 API Manager

Tags: security, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I do not want to use the default store authentication rather i want to use some different algorithms. It seems like by default it uses sha-256 and associated with salt.

1. Lets say I want to remove the salt authentication and keep only SHA-256.
2. Can i change the same to ensure the store signed up users are secured via my own algorithm?

Please guide me to solve this issue.

Comment: What do you mean by store authentication? Do you mean SSL encryption algorithms?

Comment: In Store, user is signing up and that credentials are getting stored in WSO2Carbon DB in a table called UM_USER . I want to know the encryption algorithm followed by wso2 in the column UM_PASSWORD and i want to remove the addition of Salted Password..

Comment: @AbimaranKugathasan Can you please help me with this ?

Comment: any luck on this pls